# How to position an arrow based on the position of a different object on the page in Javascript/Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I've created a script that positions a box on page based off of the position of an element on hover. Works just fine, however in addition the moving said box, I want to position an arrow inside the box to point at the hovered over element. I just can't figure out how to though.

I've tried positioning it horizontally similarly to how I positioned it vertically using, but that doesn't even come close to being correct. My javascript:

```
docSize = $('innerbody').getSize();
hint_obj = $('hint_obj');
hint_arr = hint_obj.getChildren('.hint_arr')[0];

$$('.item').addEvents({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        var el = e.target;
        var elemPosition = el.getPosition();
        hint_obj.setStyle('bottom', (docSize.y - elemPosition.y - 80));
        hint_arr.setStyle('left', (docSize.x - elemPosition.x));
    },
    mouseout: function(e) {
        hint_obj.setStyle('bottom', null);
    }
});
```

I've made a mockup of what I'm attempting to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/0jowade8/2/

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you would like? http://jsfiddle.net/0jowade8/3/

Comment: Well, that actually worked for positioning the arrow, but not the box, but I was able to adapt it and get it working (one variable for positioning the box, and one variable for positioning the arrow).

Comment: on top of sergio's bit, using delegation you can do it with a single event locally with the right context http://jsfiddle.net/0jowade8/4/ - but it can be simplied further still and even solved with CSS only.

Answer (score 2):

As [Dimitar Christoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468965/how-to-position-an-arrow-based-on-the-position-of-a-different-object-on-the-page#comment41577595_26468965) mentioned, it can be solved with CSS only by using `:after` pseudo-element.

```
.item:hover:after {
    border-bottom: 14px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    border-left: 14px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 14px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 66px;
    left: 26px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4mmxypm9/)**

Comment: My problem with this solution (even though it would work), in my case the final product will have additional effects attached to the box (and subsequently the arrow sitting inside of it). While I could have just added said animations to the arrow separately, it seems like a waste of memory to animate two separate objects if I can get away with animating just one. Thank you anyways.